# Unable to disable text box using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I've following login form which has two HTML5 text boxes with required valdation:

```
<div id="SignUpForm" class="loginContainer">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 20px">
        <div class="triangle">
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="loginForm" align="left">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" class="style1">
                <input id="txtCustEmailID" type="email" name="txtCustEmailID" placeholder="Enter Email ID"
                    required style="width: 195px" />
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Button ID="btnCustLogin" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="btnCustLogin_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" class="style1">
                <input id="txtCustPwd" name="txtCustPwd" type="password" required placeholder="Enter Password"
                    style="width: 193px" />
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel('txtCustEmailID','txtCustPwd','SignUpForm')" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left" style="font-size: medium; color: #FFFFFF;">
                <a href="#RegOnSrchdialog" name="modal" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold"
                    onclick="EnableRegFormTxt('txtCustEmailID','txtCustPwd','SignUpForm')">Register</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

On clicking the anchor tag "Register" I am calling a javascript function **EnableRegFormTxt** which I am using to disable the login form textboxes so that their validations will also get disabled, but this js is not working and I am not able to do any post back on the page because of validations.

The **js** is:

```
function EnableRegFormTxt(i, j, k) {
document.getElementById("txtCustFName").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustLName").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustREmail").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustRPwd").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustRePwd").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustPh").disabled = false;
document.getElementById(i).disabled = true;
document.getElementById(j).disabled = true;
document.getElementById(k).style = "display:none";
```

}

Please let me know where I am wrong.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
function makeReadOnly()
        {
         document.getElementById("TextBox1").readonly=true;         
        }
```

Call above function on click event or any other event you want.

**Here is your function:**

```
function EnableRegFormTxt(i, j, k) {
document.getElementById("txtCustFName").readonly = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustLName").readonly = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustREmail").readonly = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustRPwd").readonly = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustRePwd").readonly = false;
document.getElementById("txtCustPh").readonly = false;
document.getElementById(i).readonly = true;
document.getElementById(j).readonly = true;
document.getElementById(k).style = "display:none";
}
```

Comment: readonly behaves differently than disabled.  A disabled form input won't be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
   function DisableRegFormTxt(i, j, k) {
    document.getElementById("txtCustFName").setAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustLName").setAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustREmail").setAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustRPwd").setAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustRePwd").setAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustPh").setAttribute('readonly');

    }

    function EnableRegFormTxt(i, j, k) {
    document.getElementById("txtCustFName").removeAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustLName").removeAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustREmail").removeAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustRPwd").removeAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustRePwd").removeAttribute('readonly');
    document.getElementById("txtCustPh").removeAttribute('readonly');

    }
```